# Sum the series upto n terms.

Tags: linear-algebra, sequences-and-series, limits, summation

> Find the sum up to $n$ terms where $k_{\text{th}}$ term is $k(k+1)(k²+k+1).$

My attempt: I multiplied and divided by three then wrote $$1/3\cdot((k²+k+2)-(k²+k-1))(k²+k)(k²+k+1)$$ but couldn't succeed to make a telescoping series. Anyone doing by making a telescope would be helpful. Other methods are also welcome.

Comment: Do you know what is $ \sum k^4$?

Comment: Can you elaborate on "multiplied and divided by 3"? I don't understand how you got that term (or why you think doing that will give you a telescoping series).

Comment: I know but I want to know if it is possible by making a telescope

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always possible to make it (polynomial) into a telescope. E.g. do it term wise for $ \sum k , \sum k^2, \sum k^3 , \sum k^4 \ldots$.

The hard part is figuring out what the $u(k)$ is (without a lot of tedious guessing).

**Hint:** $(k+1)^5 - k^5 = 5(k)(k+1)(k^2+k+1) +1$ (by expanding it out)

So this should give you a very good guess for $u(k)$.

Comment: My solution was wrong and your is right! +1

Comment: Can you elaborate how you thought of this because I know this doesn't click itself.

Comment: @SMSheikh Like I said, the hard part is figuring out what $u(k)$ is. You slowly do it via $2k = k(k+1) - (k-1)k ,3 k(k+1) = k(k+1)(k+2) - (k-1)k(k+2) , \ldots $, or you could "try things randomly and wishful thinkingly hope that they work out", which it did in this case. (IE it mostly comes down to 1) willingness to try, and 2) sometimes experience helps)  E.g. Michael was trying to motivate how we could create this difference.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Let $$g(k)=(k^2+k)(k^2+k+1)=f(k+1)-f(k)$$ where $f(m)=\sum_{r=0}^na_rm^r$

$$\implies\sum_{k=1}^ng(k)=f(n+1)-f(1)$$

Clearly $a_r=0\forall r\ge6$ as the coefficients of $k^r$ is zero for $r\ge6$

Comparing the coefficients of $k^4,k^3,k^2,k,k^0$ one by one

we get

$1=a_5\binom51\iff a_5=?$

$2=\binom52a_5+\binom41a_4\implies a_4=?$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: As @Calvin Lin gave hint in which there was term "1" in right hand side , how your method took care of that

Comment: @Sheikh, don't understand your confusion. Please rephrase the statement

Comment: I mean how can you assume given kth term as f(k+1) -f(k).As if we go According to hint given by @Calvin Lin there will be constant term also in kth term but by your method f(k+1) and f(k ) has same constant term so f(k+1)-f(k) has no constant term but this a contradiction to  the hint given by Calvin Lin . correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @SMSheikh, The constant term in $$f(k+1)-f(k)=a_5+a_4+a_3+a_2+a_1$$  not all are zero, right?